# Partitioning a list based on the count of a certain marker

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, partitions

My goal is to get lists containing `k` number of `0.1`s.

For example, in `{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}`, if `k=2` then the output should be `{{0.1,0.5,0.1},{0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1}}`. If `k=3`, then the output becomes `{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}}`.  My code using patterns shows errors. How can I fix my code?

```
list = {0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}

k = 2;
list /. {sub1__, sub2___} /; Length[Cases[sub1, 0.1]] == k -> {sub1, 
   sub2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not formulated very clearly. This generates minimal (overlapping) sublists containing k number of 0.1's.

```
list = {0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3};
pos = Flatten[Position[list, 0.1]]
 (* {1, 3, 5, 7} *)

f[k_] := list[[First@# ;; Last@#]] & /@ Subsequences[pos, {k}]

f /@ Range[5]

(* 
{
{{0.1}, {0.1}, {0.1}, {0.1}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.1}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1}}, 
{}
}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your idea of using Position helped.k = 2; p = 0.1;
list = {0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3};
Map[list[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] &  , 
 Partition[
  Sort[Join[{1}, 
    lastpos = Last /@  Partition[Flatten[Position[list, p]], k]  , 
    lastpos + 1]], 2]]

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3};

f[k_] := Select[Count[#, 0.1] == k &]@
  SequenceSplit[list, {Longest[a__]} /; Count[{a}, 0.1] == k :> {a}]

f /@ Range[1, 5] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3};

f[k_] := SequenceCases[list, {a__} /; Count[{a}, 0.1] == k :> {a}];

f /@ Range[1, 5] // Column

   (*{
 {{{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.3}}},
 {{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}}},
 {{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7}}},
 {{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}}},
 {{}}
    }*)
```

Answer (score 4):

A simplification of Syed's and E. Chan-López' answers:

```
f[k_] := SequenceCases[list, _?(Count[#, 0.1] == k &)]

f /@ Range[5] // Column
```

gives

```
{{{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.3}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7}}, 
{{0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3}}, 
{}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate strategy:

```
TakeByCountOf[target_, count_Integer?Positive, data_List] :=
  TakeList[data, Differences[Prepend[Max /@ Partition[Position[data, target, 1], count], 0]]]

TakeByCountOf[.1, #, data] & /@ Range[5]
(*
   {{0.1},{0.5,0.1},{0.4,0.1},{0.7,0.1}}
   {{0.1,0.5,0.1},{0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1}}
   {{0.1,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.1}}
   {{0.1,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1}}
   {}
 *)
```

The results are different than other solutions provided because this one doesn't take extra values on the right--so the last element of a group will always equal the target. If I read the original question correctly, this matches the requirements more closely.